# How to call a function in a different class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a game that can be played with a bot or a friend. So I made a new class in which it lets the user pick who to play with and in the new class I made two buttons, first "BOT" and second "Friend".

So for these buttons, I want to call a different function that I have in my previous class to this class. How can I do that?

Code for one of the functions:

```
fun playGame(cellId: Int, buSelected: Button) {
        if (activePlayer == 1) {
            txtView.text = "Player 2 turn"
            buSelected.text = "X"
            buSelected.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
            player1.add(cellId)
            activePlayer = 2
        } else {
            txtView.text = "Player 1 turn"
            buSelected.text = "O"
            buSelected.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            player2.add(cellId)
            activePlayer = 1

        }
```

I want to call `playGame()` in a new class.

Comment: Maybe you need to see [strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). No relevant code no help.

Comment: Add more information about your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, but let me tell what I understood. When you click on either of the buttons, you are setting up the look for the selected player. Also I assume that the *previous class* you mentioned is an Activity. If that is the case, send the player information as extra message in the intent and start the Activity, with player specific selection there. Hope this helps. If you need help with the code, share your query clearly with required code snippets.